# Eigenvalue/function of Laplace Operator for Exterior of Disk - Reference Request

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

I'd like to know more about,

$$\lambda u = \nabla ^2 u$$

for unbounded domains (particularly the exterior of a disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$), but have had a hard time finding references online. Can anyone suggest a website or book that covers this in depth? i.e. How to obtain solutions, proofs, important corollaries/theorems, etc.

Comment: Have you tried separation of variablaes?

Comment: Facepalm... will try that first.... although, the reason I bring it up is because I recall that unbounded domains can dramatically alter the nature of the eigenvalues. But first things first.

Comment: It's natural to restrict to $L^2$ solutions on the exterior domain.